# Trying to access array offset on value of type null - Orientacion pls

Tags: php, mysql, null, type, warnings

Estoy comenzando con PHP y mysql, estoy editando un código open source bastante simple sobre reparación de aparatos.

En el índex me da la siguiente advertencia:

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 9

Las líneas son las siguientes desde la línea 0:

```
<?php
/* Connect To Database*/
require_once ("config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
require_once ("config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
$query_perfil=mysqli_query($con,"select * from perfil where id=1");
$rw=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_perfil);
$sql=mysqli_query($con, "select LAST_INSERT_ID(id) as last from facturas order by id desc limit 0,1 ");
$rws=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
$numero=$rws['last']+1; 
?>
```

Comment: Será porque `$rws['last'] == null`? o porque `$rws == null`?

Comment: ¿Hay registros en la tabla `facturas`? ¿El índice `id` es autoincremental? (Es necesario para que funcione [LAST_INSERTED_ID()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/last_insert_id).